# Find zeros of $f(x) = x^3 + 9x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some hints to find the zeros of  the following cubic equation
$$f(x)=x^3+9x ?$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please could you edit your answer to give us some idea of what you've tried? This will enable us to give answers that will help you understand where you're going wrong, rather than just giving you a solution!

Comment: We have $f(x)=x(x^2+9)$. Note that a product is $0$ if and only if at least one term is equal to $0$.

Comment: FOIL? $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: it means first,outer,inner,last. You use it during factoring, donkey 2009

Comment: @Donkey_2009, For some reason, it's what Americans call the distributive law when multiplying two binomials.

Comment: @Donkey_2009: "FOIL" (first, outer, inner, last) is a silly, useless acronym that in some school systems are taught to help students remember the correct order of the right-hand side terms in $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$. Why it is important to write the terms in exactly that order is not something anyone can explain, and the acronym doesn't help anyone remember that "first" stands for $ac$ rather than $ab$. (Once you know enough about multiplying through to see that $ac$ makes better sense than $ab$ you can already find all four terms, and then all "FOIL" can possibly contribute is their order.)

Comment: ... The bizarre emphasis that is put on this silly useless acronym in teaching often leads students to think it is somehow more fundamental than the plain old distributive law, and so they try to use it for everything, whether it fits or not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I wish I could upvote your comments a million times.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$x^3 + 9x = x(x^2+9).$$

Comment: And $x^2$ is non-negative !

Comment: @ModdedBear. $x^2$ isn't strict non-negative. One soluton is $x=3i$, so $x^2=-9$.

Answer (score 1):

This has three roots one real and two complex:

- The real root is $x=0$.
- The complex roots are $ x=+3i$, $x=-3i$ where $i$ denotes a square root of negative $1$.